# How to get SONAR ANLAYSIS for Oracle Forms

Tags: sonarqube, oracleforms

How to get SONAR  ANLAYSIS for Oracle Forms.

I need to have sonar analysis for oracle forms

Comment: http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=239370845

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/plsql/
This is a licensed plugin so you will have to ask for a trial.

I would recommand you read carefully  http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/plsql/installation-and-usage/ and start trying Sonar code examples.

I have some posts on my blog on analyzing PL/SQL (I suppose you should have some in your Forms project) on my blog, if you want some help on using SonarSource results ofr this techno.

Regards.